# Удалить конкрентные cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

Функция удаляет все кукисы.

```
function deleteAllCookies() {
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    var cookie = cookies[i];
    var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
    var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
    document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
}
}
```

Мне же нужно удалить только кукисы вида: `$.cookie('price_' + id, 'cookie_value');` и  `$.cookie('ing_' + id, 'cookie_value');`. Для этого я попытался изменить функцию. Однако она по прежнему удаляет все кукисы. Как добиться желаемого результата?

```
function deleteSpecificCookies() {
  var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
  var names = [' price_', ' ing_'];
  var found = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      var cookie = cookies[i];
      var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
      var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
      for( var j = 0; j < names.length; j++ ) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
      if( !found ) {
        continue;
      }
      document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const cookie = $.cookie(); // все куки в виде объекта

for (let name in cookie) {
    // проверить регуляркой чтоб имя было "price_" + любая цифра
    if (/^price_\d+$/i.test(name)) {
        // удаляем по имени
        $.removeCookie(name, {path: '/'});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

И еще одно решение на чистом JS, уже для фана

```
// массив всех кукисов
const cookie = document.cookie.split(';');

// массив только из имен кукисов
const cookieName = cookie.map(item => {
    const name = item.split('=')[0]; // берем имя
    return name.trim(); // обрезаем пробел с лева
});

cookieName.forEach(name => {
    // проверить регуляркой чтоб имя было "price_" + любая цифра
    if (/^price_\d+$/i.test(name)) {
        // удаляем
        document.cookie = `${name}=;max-age=0;path=/`;
    }
});
```